# Chart title does not update

Tags: excel, vba, charts, drop-down-menu

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = TRUE
    
    If Target.Address(0, 0) = "B6" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = FALSE
        
        If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
            Call GraphOn
        Else
            Call GraphOff
        End If

        Application.EnableEvents = TRUE
        
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Where the modules GraphOn and GraphOff are defined as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GraphOn()
    
    Sheet1.Activate
    
    If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        Sheet1.ChartObjects.Delete
    End If
    
    Sheet1.Range("H2:L49").Select
    
    Sheet1.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
    
    With Sheet1.ChartObjects(1).Chart
        ' remove default chart title
        .HasTitle = False
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Caption = "PD Graphs: " & Sheet1.Cells(2, 2).Value
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

and

```
Option Explicit

    Sub GraphOff()
        
        Sheet1.Activate
        
        If ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
            Sheet1.ChartObjects.Delete
        End If
        
    End Sub
```

Cell B6 is a dropdown list which when set to "Yes" it will produce a graph with the title "PD Graphs: ", plus whatever is in cell B2 (B2 is also a dropdown list). When I select an item from the dropdown list in B2 and select B6 to be "Yes", I get the correct graph with the correct title. However, when I change B2, although the graph correctly changes, the title does not update and shows the previous title.

I have found the [following link](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?47352-Chart-title-not-updating), which seems to be relevant to my issue, but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Your Worksheet_Change event only checks for changes in B6...  Your plot title isn't dynamic - you will need to update it with code if B2 changes.

Comment: @TimWilliams How can this be accomplished? Any chance you could show a sample code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use a cell reference in a chart title, so likely the easiest way to do this would be to  link your title to a cell - see eg https://trumpexcel.com/dynamic-chart-titles-in-excel/

Comment: Eg `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartTitle.Caption = "=Test!R4C2"` Note cell address is in R1C1 format: you can set up a cell to contain the full title, then link to that.

Comment: @TimWilliams P.s. I would have accepted answer, but I am not being given the option yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a cell reference in a chart title, so likely the easiest way to do this would be to link your title to a cell - see eg https://trumpexcel.com/dynamic-chart-titles-in-excel/

Eg

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartTitle.Caption = "=Test!R4C2"
```

Note cell address
is in R1C1 format: you can set up a cell to contain the full title, then link to that.